# Primary Key Int in MySql

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I created a table:

```
create table IDTable(
keyId int not null auto_increment,
primaryId varchar(50) not null,
issueDate date,
expiryDate date,
comments varchar(255),
primary key (keyIid)
);
```

When I insert into the table, the keyId will increment by one but when I delete a row, the next insert doesn't fill up the deleted keyID. So for example if i delete a row with keyid =3, the next insert statement will not insert the row with a keyID of 3. Is there a way to set it up so the keyID is generated based on what's missing and not just by an autoincrement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated, you do not want to do that due to confusion and inconsistency.

see: [How to handle fragmentation of auto increament ID column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824600/fragmentation-of-ids-auto-increment-column-in-mysql)

For further details.
It's explained pretty neatly there.

Answer (score 2):

### No, please don't try to mess with the auto-increment key!

If you need a rank of some sort then use another column. You could use a `timestamp` to save the order when the record was inserted if that is what you want.